# How to validate the performance

Tags: postgresql

When I perform below statement in Postgres:

```
ALTER DATABASE db1 SET search_path = schm1, schm2;
```

what kind of locks will be performed on DB1?

will other users accessing the tables present in sch1,sch2,sch3 have any issue?

Comment: I don't think it will take any locks at all.

Comment: Thanks for the input .. do we have any system tables in postgres to find the performance/ statistics of an executed query ...